# IDHTTP com Delphi - HTTP request failed 401 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: delphi, http-request

Boa tarde.

Tenho um exemplo de código de requisição PUT em PHP:

```
$params["access_token"] = "### Chave de Acesso ###";
$data["Product"]["stock"] = 100;
$url = "https://{api_address}/products/123?".http_build_query($params);
ob_start();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($data)))
);
curl_exec($ch);
```

E estou tentando fazer a mesma requisição em Delphi usando IDHTTP:

```
    vToken:= rotina_que_captura_token
    vUrl:= https://clienteexemplo.commercesuite.com.br/web_api/products/89';
    vJsonProduct:= TJSONObject.Create;
    vJSonPut:= TJSONObject.Create;
    vJsonPut.AddPair('stock', '100');
    vJsonProduct.AddPair('Product', vJsonPut);
    vJsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(vJsonProduct.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);

    lHTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36';
    lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + vToken);
    Result:= lHTTP.Put(vUrl, vJsonToSend);
```

Sempre me retorna o erro: HTTP request failed 401 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, Marcelo!

Vi que na chamada em PHP, você passa o token como parâmetro na URL:

```
/products/123?".http_build_query($params);
```

Já na chamada em Delphi, você não passa o Token na URL.

```
vUrl:= 'https://clienteexemplo.commercesuite.com.br/web_api/products/89;'
```

Não conheço a API que está trabalhando, mas será que pode ser isso?

```
vUrl:= 'https://clienteexemplo.commercesuite.com.br/web_api/products/89?access_token=' + vToken;
```

Comment: Boa tarde Cleber. Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado.

Comment: É um prazer ajudar!